# how to parse a JSON object to mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

i am using a dynamic table ( in javascript) the entries put in the table are exported using JSON , i want to store these entries into a mysql table , how can i convert the object to a suitable query so that i can use php to update the sql table. Thank you

[image]

Comment: how about loop through the array store the object values in variable and then store it in mysql table

Comment: decode them to an array using `json_decode` and use them in query accordingly by iterating each record of the array.

Comment: @lokesh and Alive to Die , please help me by providing a code snippet , i am new to this

Comment: Please stop asking for code snippets, especially if you are new to this it is important that you first of all try stuff yourself, if you actually want to learn something.

Answer (score 0):

use `json_decode($obj);` in PHP
this will return array then use **loop** to get data